# How to develop jQuery drag and drop with sound effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, html, jquery-plugins

I need to create jQuery drag and drop.  when I drop item should make sound, dose anyone know how to do it? I know we can do it with HTML5 audio tag with CSS and jQuery to make it happen but I need a sample code in order to modify it.

$(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();

// need sound in my droppable

```
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
});
```

// my code

```
   $("div#gameboard div").droppable({


        drop: function (event, ui) {
            {

                sendMessage("m " + this.id + " " +
                                 localToGlobal(imgID) + " " +
                                 $(ui.helper).css("left") + " " +
                                 $(ui.helper).css("top")

                            );


            }

           myAudio.src = 'audio/song.mp3';
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not be perfectly right but here is some thing that can help you maybe:

```
var myAudio = document.createElement('audio');
myAudio.controls = true;
myAudio.src = 'Your File';
myAudio.play();
```

To make it works when you drop, you can create the audio tag before and just hit play() every drop.

I would initialise the audio tag in the ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

}
```

Then user your code:

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            .find( "p" )
                .html( "Dropped!" );

        myAudio.play();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: can you give me more specific?

Comment: can you give me an example in drag item

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the code outside of the $(document).ready(function() to get it working in my application:

```
    <script>
var myAudio = document.createElement('audio');
myAudio.controls = true;
myAudio.src = 'audio/beep.mp3';
myAudio.src = 'audio/beep.wav';
//myAudio.play();
</script>
```

Then you simply trigger the myAudio.play(); inside your drop: function code.